# When to use "depuis" and "puisque"

Tags: grammaire, sens

Both of these words mean "since" in English but I am unsure of the rules governing which one to use when. Can someone help please?

Comment: puisque is actually a causality/comparative/ because.... depuis means after/ since. depuis does not imply causality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Puisque* has a cause/effect meaning and it is used when *since* is a synonym of *because*:

> Since you are in the kitchen, could you bring me a cup of coffee?
> Puisque tu es dans la cuisine, pourrais-tu m'apporter une tasse de café ?

*Depuis* is for the cases where *since* have a meaning of time, space or when we are speaking about series:

Time:

> This company is serving customers since 1892.
> Cette société est au service des ses clients depuis 1892.

Space:

> You have been bothering me since Paris!
> Tu m'ennuies depuis Paris !

Serie:

> They are all there, from the first to the last.
> Ils sont tous là, depuis le premier jusqu'au dernier.

Mind that this one could also, in a less formal way translate to

> Ils sont tous là, du premier au dernier.

Comment: Thank you! Good quality answer.

Comment: That second example is time, isn't it - more or less the same as *depuis le moment qu'on a quitté Paris*, but a bit less emphatic. I think space would have to be depuis + lieu, e.g *correspondances depuis la gare du nord*, *trajet depuis Hanoi* ...

Comment: Paris is a location not a time. Although, yes, that might imply that "and so it is a long time" so it is the same as your example. See point 2 there: https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9D1606

Comment: Yes Paris is a location, but your example doesn't say *depuis Paris*, it it says *depuis qu'on a quitté Paris*, which is a reference to a point in time. I think your translation into English is correct, and the English obviously refers to a time.